# F-1 rocket engine composition

Tags: rockets, propulsion, engines

I was wondering if anyone can tell me what the composition of the Saturn V's F-1 engine's nozzles are? I have looked online and they have many different statistics but I cannot find out what they were made of, can anyone help?

Comment: Found [this document about the F-1](https://history.msfc.nasa.gov/saturn_apollo/documents/F-1_Engine.pdf) which describes the engine in some detail regarding design, arrangement, and operation, but makes almost no mention of materials used. However, one might infer from the document that it was principally copper and stainless steel - copper combustion chamber, stainless everywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [F-1 Engine Fact Sheet](https://history.msfc.nasa.gov/saturn_apollo/documents/F-1_Engine.pdf) states that the "nozzle extension" (the part of the nozzle below the turbine exhaust manifold) was made of high strength stainless steel.

The "thrust chamber", including the portion of the nozzle above the turbine exhaust manifold, was formed from tubes constructed of Inconel X-750, a high-temperature, heat-treatable, nickel base alloy. ([reference](http://heroicrelics.org/info/f-1/f-1-thrust-chamber.html))

[image]